# Find the basis in W solutions of the homogeneous system of linear equations.

Tags: vector-spaces, change-of-basis

The subspace $W$ is given as space of solutions of the following homogeneous system of linear equations. Find the basis in $W$ :
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{r}
2 x_{1}+2 x_{2}-x_{3}+x_{5}=0 \\
-x_{1}-x_{2}+2 x_{3}-3 x_{4}+5 x_{5}=0 \\
x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}-3 x_{4}+6 x_{5}=0
\end{array}\right.
$$

what i have i tried:

$\left\{\begin{array}{l}0+0+3 x_{3}-6 x_{4}+11 x_{5}=0 \\ 0 + 0+x_{3}+0+11 x_{5}=0 \\ x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}-3 x_{4}+6 x_{5}=0\end{array}\right.$
$\left\{\left.\begin{array}{ccccc}0 & 0 & 3 & -6 & 11 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 11 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & -3 & +6\end{array}\right|_{0} ^{0}\right.$
$\left.\left.\delta\left(\begin{array}{c}-\gamma+\frac{\alpha}{3} \\ \gamma \\ \frac{-\alpha-\beta}{\beta^{3}}\end{array}\right)\right|_{N} ^{0} \alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}\right\} \quad x_{1}+x_{2}=\frac{x_{5}}{3} \rightarrow x_{1}=-\gamma+\frac{\alpha}{5}$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, $W$ does not have a unique basis, so maybe you wish to find $\underline{\textbf{a}}$ basis of $W$.
In general, to solve this type of exercises, we apply [Gauss-Jordan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) elimination. Let $A$ be the matrix of the system.
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\ -1 & -1 & 2 & -3 & 5 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & -3 & 6 \end{pmatrix}$$
After performing some row opetations we get that the row echelon form of $A$ is:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 3 & 0 & -3 & 7 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 & -6 & 11 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Thus,
$\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      x_5 = \lambda_1 \\
      x_4 = \lambda_2 \\
      x_3 = \frac{-11}{3}\lambda_1 + 2 \lambda_2 \\
      x_2 = \lambda_3 \\
      x_1 = \frac{-7}{3}\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 -\lambda_3
\end{array} 
\right. $
and hence a basis fow $W$ would be
$\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      f_1 = (-7, 0, -11, 0, 3) \\
      f_2 = (1, 0, 2, 1, 0) \\
      f_3 = (-1, 1, 0, 0, 0) \\
\end{array} 
\right. $